# How to automatically set pagebreak when printing?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of data inserted by the user in the excel sheet. I created a command button for ptinting. Since the data will be added by the user in future, so I cannot set the page break. I want to page break to be at the proper position.

[image]

For example the image above, I don't want to print for data group in different page. If there is no enough space for data3 to be printed on the same sheet as data and data 2, the page break automatically adjust data3 into a new page.

This is the code that I have

```
Sub pagebreak()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long, rngTemp As Range

lastrow = Sheet2.Range("E1").Offset(Rows.count - 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngTemp = Sheet2.Range("E11")

Do While rngTemp.Row <> lastrow
    Set rngTemp = Sheet2.Range("E11", rngTemp.Offset(75)).Find(What <> vbNull, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    rngTemp.Parent.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=rngTemp.Offset(1, -7)
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Based on the code above, I will put the max data for 75 rows only in one page. To avoid improper page break, I will check for the separation part (the blank grey row) which I already put some keyword at the side (test for non blank). However this code does not work. Can someone help to fix the code?

Comment: We aren't a 'write some code for me' website; please show what you've attempted (we need a [mcve]).

Comment: @cybermonkey sorry for the incomplete question. I already edited the question.

Comment: The question of how many rows of a worksheet will fit on a page is notoriously difficult to answer in Excel. Excel itself offers to shrink row height which offers a solution in itself but makes any other solution even more difficult. You will have to first lower your expectations. Then you will have to invest many hours in research and programming which will be worth while because you will learn a lot. Finally, you will have to settle for about half of your lowered expectations. I speak from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Loop up from row 75 and look for empty cells (the grey ones).

```
Sub PBs()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 75 To 1 Step -1  ' loop backwards from row 75 to find the first empty cell

     If IsEmpty(Cells(x, 1)) Then

         ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Cells(x, 1)
         Exit For

     End If

Next x

End Sub
```

You mentioned that the worksheet should always be 75 rows, if this is not the case (e.g. the user has increased the size of the rows) you'll have to look at measuring the height of each row as per my comment.

Comment: The code works fine, but it will set the page break for each data. What I want is to put the maximum set of data in one page, not each data separated with blank row in one page.

Comment: Ok, then you need to check how many points each row takes up, how many points per page depending on your margins etc, find the closest row to the number of points and add the break there. I have a meeting now but I'll amend my post later. Feel free to have a go yourself and post the result in the meantime ;)

Comment: I already check the maximum row per page is 75 rows. The data are dynamic based on the user. That is why I need to cap the maximum row per page and check for the end of previous data. Please refer to the code in my question. Hope you can fix my code. I do not know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: @mfo_28 - post amended for your 75 rows

Comment: the code works fine for the first 75 row, what about for the next 75 row after that? I tried to modify your code. but still does not work

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a code writing service, I can't do it all for you. Take what I've done as a starting point and modify it e.g. add other loops for row 150, 225 etc